# Chaning theme based on system Theme

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

How can I set the Theme to system theme when the User wants system theme and when the user wants custom theme set it to custom. It always gives me the same error

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 888 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: ThemeData#69a95. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

This is my code

```
  Widget themeSwitcherDropdown() {
    return Consumer<ThemeManager>(
      builder: (cont, themeManager, _) {
        return DropdownButton<ThemeData>(
          value: themeManager.currentTheme,
          onChanged: (newTheme) {
            themeManager.setTheme(newTheme!);
          },
          items: themeManager.getAvalibleThemes().entries.map((entry) {
            final name = entry.key;
            final theme = entry.value;

            return DropdownMenuItem<ThemeData>(
              value: theme,
              child: Text(name),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

ThemeManager

```
  BuildContext context;

  ThemeManager(this.context);

  ThemeData _currentTheme = ThemeData.light();
  ThemeData get currentTheme => _currentTheme;

  Map<String, ThemeData> getAvalibleThemes() {
    Map<String, ThemeData> availableThemes = {
      "Light": ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),
      "Dark": ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true),
      "System": ThemeData.light(),
      // Add more themes as needed
    };
    return availableThemes;
  }

  ThemeData getSystemTheme() {
    Brightness brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      return ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true).copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.purple));
    } else {
      return ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true).copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple));
    }
  }

  void setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    if (theme == ThemeData.light()) {
      theme = getSystemTheme();
    }
    _currentTheme = theme;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I am trying to change the theme based on users input from dropdown menu but it always gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

to use system theme as a default in your app you need to use this in your materialapp `themeMode: ThemeMode.system,` then default mobile theme will be same to app theme.